# Non-linear axes for imshow in matplotlib

Tags: image, plot, matplotlib, logarithm

I am generating 2D arrays on log-spaced axes (for instance, the x pixel coordinates are generated using `logspace(log10(0.95), log10(2.08), n)`.

I want to display the image using a plain old imshow, in its native resolution and scaling (I don't need [to stretch it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1679126/125507); the data itself is already log scaled), but I want to add ticks, labels, lines that are in the correct place on the log axes.  How do I do this?

Ideally I could just use commands line `axvline(1.5)` and the line would be in the correct place (58% from the left), but if the only way is to manually translate between logscale coordinates and image coordinates, that's ok, too.

For linear axes, using `extents=` in the call to imshow does what I want, but I don't see a way to do the same thing with a log axis.

Example:

```
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

x = logspace(log10(10), log10(1000), 5)
imshow(vstack((x,x)), extent=[10, 1000, 0, 100], cmap='gray', norm=LogNorm(), interpolation='nearest')
axvline(100, color='red')
```

This example does not work, because extent= only applies to linear scales, so when you do axvline at 100, it does not appear in the center.  I'd like the x axis to show 10, 100, 1000, and `axvline(100)` to put a line in the center at the 100 point, while the pixels remain equally spaced.

Comment: Can you have some working code or image of what you want to achieve. Another question is whether you are flexible about using pcolor instead of imshow.

Comment: @imsc: added an example.  I think pcolor is fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, it works fine.  I'm confused.

Previously I was getting errors about "Images are not supported on non-linear axes" which is why I asked this question.  But now when I try it, it works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.logspace(1, 3, 5)
y = np.linspace(0, 2, 3)
z = np.linspace(0, 1, 4)
Z = np.vstack((z, z))

plt.imshow(Z, extent=[10, 1000, 0, 1], cmap='gray')
plt.xscale('log')

plt.axvline(100, color='red')

plt.show()
```

This is better than `pcolor()` and `pcolormesh()` because

1. it's not insanely slow and
2. is interpolated nicely without misleading artifacts when the image is not shown at native resolution.

Comment: I am equally confused. Previously, I tried `imshow` with `log` and it did not work, however it is working perfectly now.

Comment: We found that if you remove `extent` it won't work. That is, `plt.imshow(Z,cmap='gray'); plt.xscale('log')` raises the error.

Comment: @developer oh maybe because the default extent starts at 0?

Comment: When using the code above with matplotlib 1.4.3 I still get warnings: `C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py:1166: UserWarning: aspect is not supported for Axes with xscale=log, yscale=linear
  'yscale=%s' % (xscale, yscale))` and `C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py:359: UserWarning: Images are not supported on non-linear axes.
  warnings.warn("Images are not supported on non-linear axes.")` Obviously it does not work correctly as aspect ratio is wrong etc. Not recommended to use this.

Comment: Did this stop working in MPL2?  ... probably: http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/users/whats_new.html#non-linear-scales-on-image-plots

Comment: Is this still working? I don't get any errors, but the image is stretch and deformed by the log scale. Like I would want all the squares to be the same size but they aren't.

Comment: I get wrong axis values using a non-uniform date axis with imshow. No errors, but the axis is clearly wrong :/ (each pixel is associated with a fixed date, but the dates represented in the image is slightly non-uniform)

Comment: I think it does not work anymore, I also have stretched image. In the example provided @endolith, there are 4 different values that should change for x= 31.6, 100, and 316. However in the image the changes are around 250, 500 and 750. Something is clearly not working as expected! Anyone got a reference on how to do it?

Answer (score 22):

In my view, it is better to use `pcolor` and regular (non-converted) x and y values. `pcolor` gives you more flexibility and regular x and y axis are less confusing.

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from matplotlib.ticker import LogFormatterMathtext

x=np.logspace(1, 3, 6)
y=np.logspace(0, 2,3)
X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
z = np.logspace(np.log10(10), np.log10(1000), 5)
Z=np.vstack((z,z))

im = plt.pcolor(X,Y,Z, cmap='gray', norm=LogNorm())
plt.axvline(100, color='red')

plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')

plt.colorbar(im, orientation='horizontal',format=LogFormatterMathtext())
plt.show()
```

[image]

As `pcolor` is slow, a faster solution is to use `pcolormesh` instead.

```
im = plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z, cmap='gray', norm=LogNorm())
```

Comment: This looks like it would solve my problem.  Here's a simpler example that gets at what I was trying to solve: https://gist.github.com/3124528  So pcolor is like an extremely slow imshow that draws each pixels as a rectangle?  There's no way to do `xscale('log')` with imshow?

Comment: `pcolormesh` looks like a faster way to do the same thing.  "pcolormesh uses a QuadMesh, a faster generalization of pcolor, but
with some restrictions."  Not sure what those restrictions are, but it seems to work.

Comment: `pcolormesh` seems to be a nice alternative. One of the restrictions is it can not be used with masked coordinate arrays.

Comment: unfortunately this results in interpolation errors in the resulting image compared to imshow, which does good interpolation.  :/   waiiiiit a second..... I just tried imshow with extent and followed by `xscale('log')` and it works fine.

Comment: Can you put your solution as a new answer.

Answer (score -2):

To display imshow with abscisse log scale:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(nrow, ncol, i+1)
ax.set_xscale('log')
```