# Log x-scale in imshow :: matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a table which looks like this

[image]

I have the highlighted part as a matrix of which I want to do an `imshow`. I want to have the x-scale of the plot logarithmic, as one can understand by looking at the parameter values in the topmost row. How to do this is matplotlib?

Comment: You **cannot** apply `log` scale on an image. It does not make any sense. `imshow` gets an array in a sense every value is a pixel value. So in your image (i.e., your table) 67 is just a pixel to which 64 is the next. It does not care to your scaling concept.

Comment: @Developer it may not make sense for pure image analysis *per se*, but three dimensional data, displayed as an image, can have logarithmic scales. For this `pcolor` is appropriate per my answer.

Comment: @PaulH The confusing part is that SO says a `matrix`. Your `pcolor` solution is great however in which you're assigning coordinates for every cell! In *Excel 2007+* one may easily colorise the matrix (conditional formatting) but the concept and usage here is still not clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-linear axes for imshow in matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488800/non-linear-axes-for-imshow-in-matplotlib)

Comment: @Developer: I understand that a `log` scale in `imshow` does not make sense as it is a pixel by pixel representation of a matrix. But what I want to show by the color is a quantity which depends on two variables `x` and `y` and I have values of this quantity for `x=10,100,1000` and so on, so I need to make the x-scale of the density plot logarithmic.
@PaulH: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You want to use `pcolor`, not `imshow`. Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
Z = np.random.random(size=(7,7))
x = 10.0 ** np.arange(-2, 5)
y = 10.0 ** np.arange(-4, 3)
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.pcolor(x, y, Z)
```

Which give me:

[image: log pcolor]

Comment: It might be better to use `pcolormesh` (as it is faster)

Comment: Do you know by any chance how to align the CENTER of the square with the x, y coordinates and not the lower-left corner?

Comment: @AnnaChristine see the documentation for the `shading` argument: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor.html