# Trying to plot a colormap in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, heatmap, colormap

So I'm trying to plot a colormap in python, not really sure how to go about doing it. At this point, I don't really care what colors are used, I'd just like them to be in a 10x10 grid. I've toyed around with matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d, but I'm not familiar enough with the arguments or plotting in general to get it to work.

This is what I want it to look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKEFm.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here are my values:

x = [1000.0, 1500.0, 2000.0, 2500.0, 3000.0, 3500.0, 4000.0, 4500.0, 5000.0, 5500.0]

y = [50.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 250.0, 300.0, 350.0, 400.0, 450.0, 500.0]

z = [[4881.8642105816871, 10911.715059458633, 14155.013920191856, 15445.716752715813, 16013.555045427016, 15930.210275343226, 14914.871694262614, 13066.110673589264, 10759.038539701312, 8463.0016244336093], [1974.871155086661, 1145.8564488717275, 360.21552184520687, 93.26083185814899, 21.427562046024793, 7.0515082675648033, 8.9490523628452756, 14.879083651382828, 21.096831336382142, 26.546911264223507], [1634.3004731594849, 596.47348127936391, 112.49120675840454, 15.812850921622774, 4.0543288410416025, 9.0618094371920641, 16.389066614461047, 22.915048528916472, 28.13970763744614, 32.19301414581065], [1986.732401772239, 799.55302793978888, 160.97797226074397, 24.950029150759416, 2.9740612607771544, 5.1831654930427353, 11.868454452741116, 18.423909277895582, 23.871268732800026, 28.176932672588872], [2601.7028764095298, 1395.8441541583775, 350.7791306410262, 76.264494509924447, 12.917045956205232, 2.0917899539090037, 4.7536763606740866, 10.386333025075864, 15.994635925645284, 20.802037330766186], [3293.2621749740892, 2468.8337536368813, 794.89657520857122, 231.80120180328421, 69.115519256908826, 22.56546362231742, 11.68385698697284, 12.181871134288121, 16.036344120838468, 20.480043889445149], [3946.9123317902149, 4077.9829695428052, 1678.9233197571568, 607.05248741635501, 240.16635849955915, 112.17393601200131, 66.792078445172521, 51.930124965393659, 48.76103688333918, 50.00623950373992], [4502.107788994359, 6161.1060688041271, 3218.1802555799272, 1379.0348763810446, 640.22321406877404, 349.14793361033742, 228.99173439562361, 178.00469532465459, 156.84445929086453, 148.55111237018477], [4948.2311747056465, 8553.3089397606091, 5603.5794468290587, 2781.2587849125666, 1439.9934016139214, 853.84661084199092, 589.64424718785426, 466.19185775513267, 405.81332964558175, 375.96900504309684], [5292.3370996081712, 11038.242790006936, 8921.6574107649831, 5087.0863086276313, 2867.5539374519794, 1796.784239152586, 1281.1061782196334, 1023.8418898637763, 890.53738452759285, 817.7523115877392]]

Answer (score 4):

```
x = [1000.0, 1500.0, 2000.0, 2500.0, 3000.0, 3500.0, 4000.0, 4500.0, 5000.0, 5500.0]

y = [50.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 250.0, 300.0, 350.0, 400.0, 450.0, 500.0]

z = [[4881.8642105816871, 10911.715059458633, 14155.013920191856, 15445.716752715813, 16013.555045427016, 15930.210275343226, 14914.871694262614, 13066.110673589264, 10759.038539701312, 8463.0016244336093], [1974.871155086661, 1145.8564488717275, 360.21552184520687, 93.26083185814899, 21.427562046024793, 7.0515082675648033, 8.9490523628452756, 14.879083651382828, 21.096831336382142, 26.546911264223507], [1634.3004731594849, 596.47348127936391, 112.49120675840454, 15.812850921622774, 4.0543288410416025, 9.0618094371920641, 16.389066614461047, 22.915048528916472, 28.13970763744614, 32.19301414581065], [1986.732401772239, 799.55302793978888, 160.97797226074397, 24.950029150759416, 2.9740612607771544, 5.1831654930427353, 11.868454452741116, 18.423909277895582, 23.871268732800026, 28.176932672588872], [2601.7028764095298, 1395.8441541583775, 350.7791306410262, 76.264494509924447, 12.917045956205232, 2.0917899539090037, 4.7536763606740866, 10.386333025075864, 15.994635925645284, 20.802037330766186], [3293.2621749740892, 2468.8337536368813, 794.89657520857122, 231.80120180328421, 69.115519256908826, 22.56546362231742, 11.68385698697284, 12.181871134288121, 16.036344120838468, 20.480043889445149], [3946.9123317902149, 4077.9829695428052, 1678.9233197571568, 607.05248741635501, 240.16635849955915, 112.17393601200131, 66.792078445172521, 51.930124965393659, 48.76103688333918, 50.00623950373992], [4502.107788994359, 6161.1060688041271, 3218.1802555799272, 1379.0348763810446, 640.22321406877404, 349.14793361033742, 228.99173439562361, 178.00469532465459, 156.84445929086453, 148.55111237018477], [4948.2311747056465, 8553.3089397606091, 5603.5794468290587, 2781.2587849125666, 1439.9934016139214, 853.84661084199092, 589.64424718785426, 466.19185775513267, 405.81332964558175, 375.96900504309684], [5292.3370996081712, 11038.242790006936, 8921.6574107649831, 5087.0863086276313, 2867.5539374519794, 1796.784239152586, 1281.1061782196334, 1023.8418898637763, 890.53738452759285, 817.7523115877392]]

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
%matplotlib inline
p.imshow(z,interpolation='none',cmap=p.cm.jet,origin='lower')  
# many other colormaps can be seen here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html
p.colorbar()
```

[image]

Note the `inline` command is just needed for Ipython. Outside Ipython you might need a `p.show()`.

Comment: Do you know how to make the coloring logarithmic? I'd like to see more contrast in the area that is now very blue.

Comment: That is indeed very often desirable (especially in spectra, ie. 2D FFTs) and to see the noise floor. I simply take the log of the data and plot the log case right next to it. Your exact question came up elsewhere (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478460/logarithmic-yscale-in-imshow)  but I can't find an answer that would do w/o explicitly taking the log of the data.

Answer (score 1):

roadrunner66 has given the answer, maybe I can be a little more accurate with the matplotlib part.

I think that it's better to script this part like this :

```
x = [1000.0, 1500.0, 2000.0, 2500.0, 3000.0, 3500.0, 4000.0, 4500.0, 5000.0, 5500.0]

y = [50.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 250.0, 300.0, 350.0, 400.0, 450.0, 500.0]

z = [[4881.8642105816871, 10911.715059458633, 14155.013920191856, 15445.716752715813, 16013.555045427016, 15930.210275343226, 14914.871694262614, 13066.110673589264, 10759.038539701312, 8463.0016244336093], [1974.871155086661, 1145.8564488717275, 360.21552184520687, 93.26083185814899, 21.427562046024793, 7.0515082675648033, 8.9490523628452756, 14.879083651382828, 21.096831336382142, 26.546911264223507], [1634.3004731594849, 596.47348127936391, 112.49120675840454, 15.812850921622774, 4.0543288410416025, 9.0618094371920641, 16.389066614461047, 22.915048528916472, 28.13970763744614, 32.19301414581065], [1986.732401772239, 799.55302793978888, 160.97797226074397, 24.950029150759416, 2.9740612607771544, 5.1831654930427353, 11.868454452741116, 18.423909277895582, 23.871268732800026, 28.176932672588872], [2601.7028764095298, 1395.8441541583775, 350.7791306410262, 76.264494509924447, 12.917045956205232, 2.0917899539090037, 4.7536763606740866, 10.386333025075864, 15.994635925645284, 20.802037330766186], [3293.2621749740892, 2468.8337536368813, 794.89657520857122, 231.80120180328421, 69.115519256908826, 22.56546362231742, 11.68385698697284, 12.181871134288121, 16.036344120838468, 20.480043889445149], [3946.9123317902149, 4077.9829695428052, 1678.9233197571568, 607.05248741635501, 240.16635849955915, 112.17393601200131, 66.792078445172521, 51.930124965393659, 48.76103688333918, 50.00623950373992], [4502.107788994359, 6161.1060688041271, 3218.1802555799272, 1379.0348763810446, 640.22321406877404, 349.14793361033742, 228.99173439562361, 178.00469532465459, 156.84445929086453, 148.55111237018477], [4948.2311747056465, 8553.3089397606091, 5603.5794468290587, 2781.2587849125666, 1439.9934016139214, 853.84661084199092, 589.64424718785426, 466.19185775513267, 405.81332964558175, 375.96900504309684], [5292.3370996081712, 11038.242790006936, 8921.6574107649831, 5087.0863086276313, 2867.5539374519794, 1796.784239152586, 1281.1061782196334, 1023.8418898637763, 890.53738452759285, 817.7523115877392]]

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p

fig1, ax1 = p.figure(1)
plot = ax1.imshow(z,interpolation='none',cmap=p.cm.jet,origin='lower')  
fig1.colorbar(plot, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_xlabel('label in x')
ax1.set_ylabel('label in y')
ax1.set_title('title')
p.show()
```

As this way, it's very clear ;) Mainly if you need to plot others heatmaps ;)