# Basic plotting of wavelet analysis output in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, wavelet, pywt

I am discovering wavelets in practice thanks to the python module [pywt](http://www.pybytes.com/pywavelets/).

I have browsed [some examples of the pywt module usage](https://github.com/nigma/pywt/tree/master/demo), but I could not grasp the essential step: I don't know how to display the multidimensionnal output of a wavelet analysis **with matplotlib**, basically.

This is what I tried, (given one pyplot axe `ax`):

```
import pywt

data_1_dimension_series = [0,0.1,0.2,0.4,-0.1,-0.1,-0.3,-0.4,1.0,1.0,1.0,0] 
# indeed my data_1_dimension_series is much longer

cA, cD = pywt.dwt(data_1_dimension_series, 'haar')

ax.set_xlabel('seconds')
ax.set_ylabel('wavelet affinity by scale factor')

ax.plot(axe_wt_time, zip(cA,cD))
```

or also

```
data_wt_analysis = pywt.dwt(data_1_dimension_series, 'haar')
ax.plot(axe_wt_time, data_wt_analysis)
```

Both `ax.plot(axe_wt_time, data_wt_analysis)` and `ax.plot(axe_wt_time, zip(cA,cD))` are not appropriate and returns error. Both throws `x and y must have the same first dimension`

The thing is `data_wt_analysis` does contain several 1D series, one for each wavelet scale factor. 
I surely could display as many graphs as there are scale factors. But I want them all in the same graph.

How could I simply display such data, in only one graph, **with matplotlib** ?

Something like the colourful square below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should extract the different 1D series from your array of interest, and use matplotlib as in most simple example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

[from doc.](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html)

You wish to superimpose 1D plots (or line plots). So, if you have lists l1, l2, l3, you will do

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(l1)
plt.plot(l2)
plt.plot(l3)
plt.show()
```

For a scalogram: what i used was `imshow()`. This was not for wavelets, but same ID: a colormap.

I have found [this sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6788842/356440) for use of `imshow()` with wavelets, didn t try thought

```
from pylab import *
import pywt
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile

# Find the highest power of two less than or equal to the input.
def lepow2(x):
    return 2 ** floor(log2(x))

# Make a scalogram given an MRA tree.
def scalogram(data):
    bottom = 0

    vmin = min(map(lambda x: min(abs(x)), data))
    vmax = max(map(lambda x: max(abs(x)), data))

    gca().set_autoscale_on(False)

    for row in range(0, len(data)):
        scale = 2.0 ** (row - len(data))

        imshow(
            array([abs(data[row])]),
            interpolation = 'nearest',
            vmin = vmin,
            vmax = vmax,
            extent = [0, 1, bottom, bottom + scale])

        bottom += scale

# Load the signal, take the first channel, limit length to a power of 2 for simplicity.
rate, signal = wavfile.read('kitten.wav')
signal = signal[0:lepow2(len(signal)),0]
tree = pywt.wavedec(signal, 'db5')

# Plotting.
gray()
scalogram(tree)
show()
```

Comment: but in such case, all will have the same `y=0` origin. I'm gonna add an image for what I want. I have read it's called a scalograme.

Comment: I have added an image corresponding.

Comment: well I also have gone through this sample, but I don't understand all the steps. And I don't know what is a MRA tree...

Comment: it is what you get out of `tree = pywt.wavedec(signal, 'db5')`, you should try this method and see the format of output